# Algorithm to match redirect URLs when migrating a website

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, string-matching, fuzzy-search

Lets say we have two sets of URLs: The *source pool* and the *target pool*. The source pool is basically a flat list of URLs present on a website, while the target pool contains all URLs of a remade version of the same website. So for *most* entries in the source pool, there should be corresponding, similar entry in the target pool.

We want to create a redirect map by matching one URL from the *target pool* to each URL in the *source pool*. The same *target* can be mapped to multiple *sources*.

**Example source pool:**

```
/books/faust
/books/romeo-and-juliet
/ebooks/from-zero-to-hero
/blog
/about-us
/deprecated-page
```

**Example target pool:**

```
/books/goethe/faust
/books/shakespeare/romeo-and-juliet
/ebooks/random-wannabe/from-zero-to-hero
/blog
/about-us
/newly-added-page
```

*Note: Your answer shouldn't be too specific to the provided examples, like the addition of the author namespace. Rather, assume just two sets of string-based, [pretty urls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) with varying overlap/similarity. We're looking for a general solution to creating redirect maps based on the likelihood of two urls referring to the same thing.*

**So here's the question:**

1. Is there a ready-made solution for exactly this application (redirects for website migration), taking two lists of urls and returning a mapping?
2. If not, which general algorithms are suitable for electing a single most probable candidate out of a list?

Additional output of the probability of the match would help with manually checking the list later on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so to answer my own question:

1. In the mean time, a tool has come to live that is intended for exactly that application. It can be found here: https://github.com/jsphpl/redirect-mapper
2. For my current application, the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) turned out to be a good similary indicator already, but might not work that well in every situation. In theory, you can use any existing [String metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) or make up your own algorithm, that best suits your current needs.